# Scripting languages in XCode

Tags: xcode, groovy, clojure, scripting-languages

I notice that Java has a number of ancillary scripting languages. Clojure and Groovy for example. My understanding is that these can be used when the full might and power of Java does not need to be applied and a speedy cludge can be hacked in Groovy/Clojure. But at the end of the day the scripting tools contribution gets compiled into the application

Question 1. Is there a similar scripting in XCode?  I was not so interested in Python or Ruby in this situation as they are languages in their own right added in, as indeed I think can happen in Java, but I was looking for a purpose built tools.

Question 2. If there is such a tool would it count the application out vis-a-vis the new Apple guidelines as to what can be used to generate iXxx apps?

Comment: Groovy and Clojure are general-purpose languages which are in many ways much more powerful than Java (in terms of language features). I choose to use Groovy/Clojure in preference to Java because I can get the job done much quicker and with far fewer lines of code.

Comment: Sorry if i implied the the other languages were lesser than Java, it was the way i phrased it rather than a statement of fact. I have only done a little Java and none of the other languages Groovy etc. so i was basing what i said on listening to podcasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/) is a scripting language that integrates well with Objective-C/Cocoa applications. Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

For such things there is AppleScript, with its own IDE AppleScript Studio. It has bindings to control Cocoa Applications, be embedded inside of them or even work as stand-alone scripts.

The problem is that it cannot be integrated inside iXxx applications because iPhone-OS Cocoa Foundation framework doesn't include it.

Comment: and appleScript syntax is soooo awful. unless you use JavaScript OSA: http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/JavaScriptOSA/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by mipadi, you can use F-Script for Cocoa applicaitons.

If you are staying mainly in C, then [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is another option.

Comment: I will look at Lua but i am in the Objective-C space and also not sure if Lua would compile into O-C or if that would break Apples new T's and C's

Comment: Yes, that could be a 3.3.1 problem, but Lua is a C Library after all, it is not quite like the case of C compiling Gambit Scheme. In any case, because of 3.3.1, you're better off just running with C/Objective-C and forgetting about language-as-library option. In any case, for scripting XCode you can't beat Applescript and Ruby or Python. I have my own set of scripts to control `git` that way.

Comment: This new piece of information is relevant to what we have been discussing: http://www.appleoutsider.com/2010/06/10/hello-lua/